# Нужна ли последняя запятая перед "и"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, смысл, и

*Слабость же империй состоит в том, что бюрократия, став неотъемлемой частью политической структуры, стремилась поглотить слишком много доходов, особенно когда репрессии и эксплуатация порождали мятежи, и это увеличивало военные издержки.*

Проблема в том, что **увеличение военных расходов** относится **к мятежам**, а не ко всей бюрократии. Поймет ли читатель правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Советую **не ставить запятую**, так как есть общий элемент. А также **поставить все сказуемые в одном времени**. В нынешней редакции слабость империй в настоящее время вызвана поведением бюрократии в прошлом.

Кроме того, не очень хорошо звучит "поглотить слишком много доходов". Советую заменить на "поглотить слишким большую часть доходов".

Каких доходов? Доходов государства? Возможно, это понятно из широкого контекста, тогда можно не уточнять.

Странная логика была у этой бюрократии. Ее аппетиты особенно сильно возрастали именно в период увеличения расходов? Надеюсь, это не вполне очевидное положение как-то обсуждается в тексте статьи.

Добавление

С моей точки зрения, бюрократия стремится к воспрозводству самое себя и при этом поглощает все большую часть государсвенных средств. Но я не думаю, что поглощение государсвенных средств - это то, к чему она стремится. Получается  просто вредительство какое-то!

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, "Это увеличивало воееные издержки" — это простое предложение (основа — "это увеличивало") в составе сложного. А значит перед "и" нужна запятая.

Чтобы уменьшить вероятность разночтений, можно поробовать переформулировать. Например "...порождали мятежи, которые увеличивали военные издержки". Или как-то еще поиграть с формой последнего куска предложения.

Answer (score 0):

При наличии запятой оборот "особенно когда репрессии и эксплуатация порождали мятежи" воспринимается как изымаемый, поэтому "и это увеличивало военные издержки" причинно привязывается к "стремилась поглотить слишком много доходов", что искажает задуманный смысл. Однако несмотря на то, что последнее предложение ссылается на предыдущее местоимением, у обоих можно усмотреть общий элемент "особенно когда" (репрессии.... порождали мятежи и нечто=это ... увеличивало военные издержки) и на этом основании не ставить запятую. Другое решение: оставить запятую, явным образом подчинив последнее предложение предыдущему заменой сочетания "и это" на "что".

Comment: Не ставить запятую! А замена  "и это" на "что" не решает проблему; "что" можно отнести как к "стремилась поглотить", так и к  "порождали мятежи"

Answer (score 0):

1. Понятнее будет вместо "и это увеличивало..." написать "из-за которых увеличивались..."
2. Фраза выглядит длинной. Можно было бы разделить её на несколько коротких предложений.